# UIImageView doesn't show up in LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, xcasset, launch-screen

I have an image set in my asset catalog and I have it set for my UIImageView in my launch screen xib. I know the launch screen shows up because it has a label that is showing when I launch the app on my device. I can see the Image and the label in the interface builder, and even in the simulator, but when I launch the app on my device the image is not there.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and or have any good ways to troubleshoot?

I have tried quitting xcode, doing a clean, deleting the derived data reset the simulator. I have removed and added the asset I want to show up. I removed and re-did the constraints on the launch screen. I have had no success and it is driving me a bit crazy so any help is much appreciated.

Also I have two different targets so this may be contributing to the problem, but the strange thing at one point in time I did have the uiimageview showing up on the device.

Comment: What does the attributes inspector, constraints, and `.xib` file look like? Can you post screen shots?

Comment: If you change the Label on the launch screen, is that change showing when you run the app? Can you add any other objects, like a UIView with a red background, and have it show up, but the UIImageView doesn't?

Comment: yeah I can change the background color of the label and the uiimageview and the updates are made on the device @DonMag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what causes this issue, i guess when you first installed your app on your device you did not add image to your launch screen after that you've added the image next time. Right?, iOS picking up an old launch screen so I would suggest you to uninstall your app once and re-run the app.